# ¿Mi ejemplo de Spring boot me genera columnas adicionales?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

Hola a todos tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy realizando el ejemplo de Spring Rest y SQL Server de esta página

```
https://www.javaguides.net/2019/01/spring-boot-microsoft-sql-server-jpa-hibernate-crud-restful-api-tutorial.html
```

He creado la base de datos, y al ejecutar la aplicación me genera columnas adicionales, y quisiera saber porque lo hace si lo que yo deseo es usar la tabla que esta creada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo .properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTI202:1433;databasename=employees;integratedSecurity=true;
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;

    public Employee(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String emailId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    
    public Employee() {}
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que simplemente las columnas las crearas al ejecutar el código con otros nombres de atributos, y que simplemente spring no las borrara al renombrar los atributos y crear las que usas.

Prueba a cambiar `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` a `create-drop`; eso hará que al iniciar el programa borre completamente la base de datos y te la cree desde cero.

Comment: Yo no deseo que me cree tablas con JPA, sino simplemente que use las tablas que ya están creadas en base de datos.

Comment: Pues cambia el valor a `validate` y borra las columnas que sobran de forma manual.

Answer (score 0):

la forma en que me funcionó para que no me pasara que se crearan las columnas, fue modificar los atributos de las tablas: Ejemplo: Si en la base de datos hubiera una columna llamada "firstName" la modificaría a "first_name".

[Datos: En el modelo, la mejor forma de llamar a las propiedades será "firstName" ya que se recomienda de esa forma, siempre que tenga un "_" intermedio]

Comment: Wellcome to [Stack Overflow in spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) thanks for help this comunity. but you answer is in english, please translate and take a look to [How to answer ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) regards.

Comment: No hace falta modificar nada, puedes usar la anotación `@Column(name="first_name")` en el campo `private String firstName;` y ya está, JPA irá a buscar el campo first_name de la DB y guardarlo en tu variable correctamente.